# Combining database queries

Tags: mysql, sql

How can these SQL-queries to extract statistics from my database be combined for better performance?

```
$total= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as number, SUM(order_total) as sum FROM history");
$month = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as number, SUM(order_total) as sum FROM history WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -30 DAY))");
$day = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as number, SUM(order_total) as sum FROM history WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())");
```

Comment: Please try to use English when you ask here on Stack Overflow. I have edited your question to include what I think are accurate translations by using [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/).

Comment: I would suggest to try http://ru.stackexchange.com where you can ask & answer anything on Russian, and so you can formulate understable for the community.

Comment: `UNION` or `UNION ALL`

Comment: If you don't mind getting multiple rows, `UNION` or `UNION ALL` are the way to go. If you want to "collapse" this results into a single row, check my answer below.

Comment: Sorry. Firstly I confused english stackoverflow with russian stackoverflow. Secondly I confused '<=' with '>=' (I fixed it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to all the data in a single query, you have two choices:

1. Use a `UNION` query ([as sugested by bishop in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659266/combining-database-queries/32661054#32661054))
2. Tweak a query to get what you need in a single row

I'll show option 2 (option 1 has been already covered).

**Note:** I'm using user variables (that stuff in the `init` subquery) to avoid writing the expressions again and again. Also, to filter the aggregate data, I'm using `case ... end` expressions.

```sql
select 
    -- Your first query:
    count(*) as number, sum(order_total) as `sum`
    -- Your second query:
  , sum(case when `date` <= @prev_date then 1 else 0 end) as number_prev
  , sum(case when `date` <= @prev_date then order_total else 0 end) as sum_prev
    -- Your third query:
  , sum(case when `date` <= @cur_date then 1 else 0 end) as number_cur
  , sum(case when `date` <= @cur_date then order_total else 0 end) as sum_cur
from (
         select @cur_date := unix_timestamp(curdate())
              , @prev_date := unix_timestamp(date_add(curdate(), interval -30 day))
     ) as init
   , history;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Since the queries have the same column structure, you can ask MySQL to combine them with the `UNION` operation:

```
(SELECT 'total' AS kind, COUNT(*) as number, SUM(order_total) as sum FROM history~
UNION
(SELECT 'by-month' AS kind, COUNT(*) as number, SUM(order_total) as sum FROM history WHERE date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -30 DAY)))
UNION
(SELECT 'by-day' AS kind, COUNT(*) as number, SUM(order_total) as sum FROM history WHERE date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I don't understand what is 'by-month', 'by-day', and '~' in your query.

Comment: The constant columns (`total`, `by-month`, and `by-day`) label each row in the three row result set so you know which total is which.